# Using Xcode while tethered to iPhone

Tags: xcode, build, tethering

An obscure problem to be sure... I am developing on a macbook while tethered to an iPhone via USB. Therefore xcode always sees at least one device plugged-in and I never see the scheme "iOS Devices" available in xcode's scheme selection button.

I (think) I need "iOS Devices" available as a scheme selection so I can Build to the Products folder under file navigator, and then drag-n-drop the built app to my device (as opposed to the Build & Run route).

How can I still Build to the Products folder while a device is "plugged in"? (I considered tethering via wifi but thought there must surely be another way).

Comment: If the scheme is called "<your devicename>" it's still the "iOS Devices" scheme. Everything should work the same, it's just a different name.

Comment: Not sure i agree... as best I can tell, I need a scheme called "iOS Devices" to 1) "Build for archiving" and 2) To generate Products (found under the "Products" folder in the File Navigator. In the past I have simply unplugged all devices so this scheme would show up.